# How to get my code to redirect to a profile page that displays user login information of the user that is logged in. (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've tried a few times to get this code to work, but can't seem to get there. I can successfully login with a new user, but the information just keeps displaying as the default user. I made a few changes to my code, but ended up not being able to display any user data, so I went back to my mostly unchanged version to come here with.
These are the components I'm using:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Login = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const navigateToSignUp = () => {
    navigate("/signup");
  };

  const submitForm = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    fetch("http://localhost:8000/users")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        const user = data.find(
          (user) =>
            user.email &&
            user.email.toLowerCase() === email.toLowerCase() &&
            user.password &&
            user.password.toLowerCase() === password.toLowerCase()
        );
        if (user) {
          localStorage.setItem("token", user.token);
          navigate("/profile");
        } else {
          setErrorMessage("Invalid email or password");
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  };

  return (
    <div id="signin">
      <form onSubmit={submitForm}>
        <label htmlFor="email" className="email">
          Enter Email Address:
        </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="email"
          id="email"
          value={email}
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          required
        />

        <label htmlFor="password" className="password">
          Enter Password:
        </label>
        <input
          type="password"
          name="password"
          id="password"
          value={password}
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          required
        />
        <p className="signup">
          Not a member yet?{" "}
          <a id="signup" onClick={navigateToSignUp}>
            Sign up here
          </a>
        </p>

        <button type="submit" className="btn">
          Login
        </button>
      </form>
      {errorMessage && <p id="error">{errorMessage}</p>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

And this is the profile:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import React from "react";
import Welcome from "./Welcome";

const Profile = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});
  const { userId } = useParams();

  

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/users/${userId}`);
      const data = await response.json();
      setUser(data);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [userId]);

  return (
    <main>
       <section className="profilegreeting">
      <Welcome user={user} setUser={setUser} />
      </section>
        

      <p id="profileinfo">
        <span className="infotext">Name:</span>
        {user.firstname && user.lastname
          ? ` ${user.firstname} ${user.lastname}`
          : "loading..."}
        <br /> <span className="infotext">Age:</span>{" "}
        {user.age ? ` ${user.age} ` : "loading..."} <br />
        <span className="infotext">Birthday:</span>{" "}
        {user.birthday ? ` ${user.birthday} ` : "loading..."}
        <br /> <span className="infotext">Works at:</span>{" "}
        {user.job ? ` ${user.job} ` : "loading..."}
        <br /> <span className="infotext">Lives in:</span>
        {user.city && user.province && user.country
          ? ` ${user.city}, ${user.province}, ${user.country} `
          : "loading..."}
        <br /> <span className="infotext">Relationship status:</span>
        {user.relationship ? ` ${user.relationship} ` : "loading..."}
        <br />
        <br />
        <span className="infotext">Bio:</span> <br /> <br />
        {user.bio ? ` ${user.bio} ` : "loading..."}
      </p>
    </main>
  );
};

export default Profile;
```

Like I said, I have changed these quite a bit but only got errors, so I went back to what actually displayed some results, which is just the default user.

This is the json file I'm working with, also:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Doe",
    "email": "defaultuser@default.com",
    "password": "defaultpassword",
    "profilepicture": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1529946825183-536c6317f60e?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1526&q=80",
    "userposts": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "text": "Going out tonight. Who wants to join?",
        "liked": false,
        "likebutton": false
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "text": "New post",
        "liked": false,
        "likebutton": false
      }
    ],
    "newuserposts": {
      "id": 1,
      "text": "'Experience is the name everyone gives to their mistakes.' Oscar Wilde. Truer words have not been spoken. Mistakes do not need to be a negative experience so long as you learn from them.",
      "liked": false,
      "likebutton": false
    },
    "userphotos": [
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503249023995-51b0f3778ccf?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NXx8YW5vbnltb3VzfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1600&q=60",
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503248947681-3198a7abfcc9?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTZ8fGFub255bW91c3xlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1600&q=60",
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1596796867443-48bb5d2ebaa0?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTd8fGFub255bW91c3xlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1600&q=60",
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558032040-b55d2adb9745?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MjN8fGFub255bW91c3xlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1600&q=60"
    ],
    "newuserphotos": [
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1490036293550-29261601ccb9?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1974&q=80"
    ],
    "age": "26",
    "birthday": "06-23-1997",
    "job": "Mechanic at AutoShop Max",
    "city": "St. John's",
    "province": "Newfoundland and Labrador",
    "country": "Canada",
    "relationship": "In a relationship",
    "bio": "Hi everyone, I'm John Doe. I'm just a regular guy, working a regular job... Not much to say about me. I like to hike, play video games, and spend time with my loved ones.",
    "likebutton": true
  },
  {
    "email": "email@email.com",
    "password": "pass",
    "firstname": "dfsdsdf",
    "lastname": "sdfsd",
    "pfp": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1618477388954-7852f32655ec?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=928&q=80",
    "age": "20",
    "birthday": "02-20-1990",
    "job": "czxz",
    "city": "zxc",
    "province": "zxc",
    "country": "zcx",
    "relationship": "xzc",
    "bio": "zcxzccx",
    "id": 2
  }
]
```

Right now, as it displays the default user profile, the second user is getting a 404 error in the console that http://localhost:8000/users/undefined is not found. Not entirely sure on this one.

Comment: try to change 'navigate("/profile");' to 'navigate("/profile/userId");' and your defined Router must have "/:userId" to accept that parameter